# How to maintain certain number of docker images of same repository?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-image

I have set up private docker repository on my local centos machine and its working fine.

I have one project, which currently in build stage so many docker images with unique versions are getting created.

I want to keep the latest 3 docker images of that same repository and delete rest of the images of that project

How can I do that ?

Comment: Simple bash script would do. Also by "version" you mean the tag right? There are no "versions" per se when in the context of Docker containers.

Comment: the bash script will help you

Comment: @emix yes, I mean tags

Comment: @Guru Can you please provide me an example for that?

Comment: I would iterate over `docker images --filter "reference=your-app-tag-name" | tail -n +2`, sort the list, then pass the id to the `docker rmi` command.

Comment: this can help you https://github.com/TranceMaster86/docker-reg-gc/blob/master/docker-reg-gc.sh

Comment: @emix This is right, I am able to delete Docker images present on my server but unable to delete them from docker repository, Any solutions to that ?

Comment: There are lots of threads on this topic already.

Comment: yeah, I have tried **registry_cleaner.rb file method** and it runs on my local without an error also shows me logs that it removed the manifest but it won't delete any images on my docker private remote registry.

`./registry_cleaner.rb --host=http://ssandbox.test.com:5000/ --repository=app --tags_count=1`

I am using above command 

Ref: [https://github.com/oniksfly/registry_cleaner]